# Dynamically add a field to an object in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

Say I have a MATLAB object defined in a class file

```
classdef foo

   properties
      bar
   end

end
```

And I create a foo object

```
myfoo = foo();
```

Now I want to add another field to foo dynamically.  What I want is

```
myfoo.newfield = 42;
```

but this will throw an error.

I know there is a way to dynamically add a field/property to a MATLAB object but I can't remember it or find it easily in the help.  Anyone know the syntax?

Comment: What I do is add a structure as a property of the object, then I add fields to the structure. But for me it's a little unintuitive as I expect to be able to just add new properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found it.  But it's not general, only subclasses of the dynamicprops class implement it.
This is what I remember coming across.  So I suspect the general answer to this question is you can't do it.

> Any class that is a subclass of the dynamicprops class (which is itself a subclass of the   handle class) can define dynamic properties using the addprop method. The syntax is:

```
P = addprop(H,'PropertyName')
```

Comment: This behavior is very desirable behavior in my opinion. If one could arbitrarily add properties to any class, you would potentially lose a lot of robustness.

If you have an existing class that you want to make a dynamicprops class without modifying it, you can subclass both foo and dynamicprops:

`classdef dynamicfoo < foo & dynamicprops`

What else is there that could be "preventing you from doing this"?

Comment: I don't think there is a lot of robustness to begin with.  The limit on the number and names of properties is not nearly as significant as strong typing, which matlab doesn't have.  What do you lose by dynamically adding a field -- this won't break any existing code that doesn't know about the field.  But if "square" is supposed to be a "Shape," you can say obj.square = 3 and break existing code that relies on "square" being a "Shape."

The reason to do this would be to change a class that is already in memory without having to clear and reload all instances of that class.

Comment: In your June 11 comment, you ask "What do you lose by dynamically adding a field[?]" One thing is error checking - usually, if you have a Circle object, you really *don't* want to assign a (oh, let's say) "temperature."  If you wrote code like this... x = Circle(); ...lots of code, function calls, etc... x.temperature = 98.6; odds are that you made a mistake somewhere.  So, one way of looking at the DYNAMICPROPS class is to say, "hey, don't bother to error-check this object later.  If I assign to a bad 'property,' trust me, I know what I'm doing."  Up to you whether or not you want to do that.

Comment: another simple example: say you have x = Circle(); where circle has a radius property with a default value of 1. Then you write x.Radius = 3 (instead of x.radius = 3) and wonder why x.computeCircumference returns 3.1415 and not 18.8496.